# Use drop function called several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, material-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to build my folder tree in React, so far I've been able to build it properly but I'm running into a problem that when I use USE DROP the function that updates the new parent is called several times and then it always draws me the node at the main node.

I tried to move the use drop to a higher level component but no luck.

this is my whole code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import TreeView from '@mui/lab/TreeView';
import TreeItem from '@mui/lab/TreeItem';
import { DndProvider, useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        height: 240,
        flexGrow: 1,
        maxWidth: 400,
    },
});

const ItemType = 'TREE_ITEM';

const DraggableTreeItem = ({ node, moveItem, onDropItem }) => {
    const [, ref] = useDrag({
        type: ItemType,
        item: { id: node.id },
    });

    const [, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: ItemType,
        drop: (draggedItem) => {
            if (draggedItem.id !== node.id) {
                onDropItem(draggedItem.id, node.id); // Handle the drop event
            }
        },
    });

    const isExpanded = node.expanded;

    const handleToggle = () => {
        node.expanded = !node.expanded;
    };

    return (
        <div ref={(node) => ref(drop(node))}>
            <TreeItem
                onFocusCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()}
                nodeId={node.id}
                label={node.label}
                onLabelClick={handleToggle}
                onIconClick={handleToggle}
                onIconMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                expanded={isExpanded}
            >
                {node.children.map((childNode) => (
                    <DraggableTreeItem
                        key={childNode.id}
                        node={childNode}
                        moveItem={moveItem}
                        onDropItem={onDropItem}
                    />
                ))}
            </TreeItem>
        </div>
    );
};

const buildTree = (data, parentId = null) => {
    const tree = [];

    data.forEach((nodeData) => {
        if (nodeData.parentId === parentId) {
            const children = buildTree(data, nodeData.id);

            if (children.length > 0) {
                nodeData.children = children;
            }

            tree.push(nodeData);
        }
    });

    return tree;
};

const HierarchicalTreeView = ({ data }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(buildTree(data));

    const handleDropItem = (draggedItemId, newParentId) => {
        const updatedTreeData = [...treeData];

        const findNode = (nodes) => {
            for (const node of nodes) {
                if (node.id === draggedItemId) {
                    return node;
                }
                const childNode = findNode(node.children);
                if (childNode) {
                    return childNode;
                }
            }
            return null;
        };

        const draggedNode = findNode(updatedTreeData);

        if (draggedNode) {
            const removeNode = (nodes) => {
                for (const node of nodes) {
                    if (node.id === draggedItemId) {
                        const index = nodes.indexOf(node);
                        if (index !== -1) {
                            nodes.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (removeNode(node.children)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };

            removeNode(updatedTreeData);

            const findParentNode = (nodes) => {
                for (const node of nodes) {
                    if (node.id === newParentId) {
                        return node;
                    }
                    const parentNode = findParentNode(node.children);
                    if (parentNode) {
                        return parentNode;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            };

            const newParentNode = findParentNode(updatedTreeData);

            if (newParentNode) {
                newParentNode.children.push(draggedNode);
                newParentNode.expanded = true;
            }

            setTreeData([...updatedTreeData]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div>
                <h1>Material-UI TreeView with Parent-Child Hierarchy and Drag-and-Drop</h1>
                <TreeView className={classes.root}>
                    {treeData.map((node) => (
                        <DraggableTreeItem
                            key={node.id}
                            node={node}
                            moveItem={handleDropItem}
                            onDropItem={handleDropItem}
                        />
                    ))}
                </TreeView>
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    );
};
const FolderTree = () => {
    const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(buildTree( [
        {
            id: 'node-1',
            label: 'Node 1',
            parentId: null,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 'node-2',
                    label: 'Node 2',
                    parentId: 'node-1',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 'node-3',
                            label: 'Node 3',
                            parentId: 'node-2',
                            children: [],
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'node-4',
                            label: 'Node 4',
                            parentId: 'node-2',
                            children: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 'node-5',
                    label: 'Node 5',
                    parentId: 'node-1',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 'node-6',
                            label: 'Node 6',
                            parentId: 'node-5',
                            children: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
    ]));
    return (

        <div>
            {treeData &&
                <HierarchicalTreeView data={treeData} />}
            </div>
    );
}
export default FolderTree;
```